# Android Studio having problems rendering AdMob view on editor

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I've been having some problems with the Android Studio IDE when using the Google Play Services AdMob view on an application.

I've added the services to the app dependencies:
[image]

Updated the manifest with the required code, and created this view:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
android:visibility="visible" />
```

The ad is then initialized with:

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("267EF55A4F5EC1C9C51E1CFE97F4ECB2")
        .build();

adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

With that, the ad actually loads correctly:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/MSYymFY.png]

But when viewing the layout on Android Studio, the following error is shown:

[image]

Is there a way to make the IDE show the View correctly or to even suppress the error?

Comment: I don't think so but I could be wrong.

Comment: I also have the exact same problem. Anyone found the solution?